# DHTMLX calendar enable / disable in whole website

Tags: dhtmlx

I am working on website (built using PHP, Mysql, jQuery) which require that admin set a variable in configuration and according to that configuration variable jQuery autocomplete is enabled or disabled to all website. Is there any way to achieve that functionality.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it is not jquery autocomplete it is DHTMLX Calendar

Comment: What do you mean by disable? as not visible? as visible but not clickable? or calendar button does not bring calendar popup?

Comment: Just not visible. 
I want to set a variable globally in index.php and all DHTMLX calender becomes invisible.

Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to add a common id, or other attribute to all the parent elements where the schedule shows up.  Then include into your main javascript file something of the form

```
  FLAG = 1; //for visibile, or 0 for invisible
  $('#calendar').toggle(FLAG);  //OR
  $('[rel=calendar]').toggle(FLAG);
```

If you wanted that to come from php, you can always load your javascript within php:

```
  functions.js.php:
     FLAG = <?php $CAL_SETTING ?>
     //go on with the rest of the javascript



  //then include it into your html
  <script language="javascript" src="functions.js.php"></script>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

create a table setting with these fields [name, value,..] and set the name calendar_status value hide

in your view you can get read of that field from you DB and set the myCalendar.hide(true); or myCalendar.hide(false);

```
myCalendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject("DateStart"); 
myCalendar.hide(); <- you php code like <?php echo calendar_status; ?>
```